# Mouse lags when moving long distances with low sensivity

Tags: mouse, gaming

As a gamer I usually play with high sensitivity, enough so that with a flick of my wrist I can do a 180 degree turn; however, my aim has always been rough.

Recently I read something about high-ranking gamers using very low sensitivity but a really large physical mouse area to move around. The essential idea is to use your arm for large movements and wrist for small adjustment (unlike my high sensitivity style where I use my wrist for everything)

Curious about it I tried it; but, in 2 different FPS games I found my mouse would lag. I would be finished moving my hand and in the game my cross-hair would be 0.5 seconds to 1.5 seconds behind.

I have a cheap, but good Logitech M100 mouse. It has always served me very well when playing with high sensitivity.

Is this how it is for all mouses? I've read about gaming mice's DPI, though I don't see how that would solve this. In the end I would need to go even lower sensitivity, and have to move even more.

CBS.log "cannot repair" lines:

```
2017-06-22 19:48:34, Info                  CSI    00000246 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16{8}]"ehui.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-ehome-ehui, Version = 6.1.7601.17514, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2017-06-22 19:48:35, Info                  CSI    00000248 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16{8}]"ehui.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-ehome-ehui, Version = 6.1.7601.17514, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2017-06-22 19:49:37, Info                  CSI    00000367 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16{8}]"ehui.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-ehome-ehui, Version = 6.1.7601.17514, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2017-06-22 19:49:37, Info                  CSI    00000369 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16{8}]"ehui.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-ehome-ehui, Version = 6.1.7601.17514, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
```

Comment: Do you observe the same lag in non-gaming applications? For instance, on my work computer (completely non-gaming) I've observed that when dragging Outlook 2016 there is a noticeable lag and smoothing effect, but dragging any other application (including other Office applications) has no such lag or smoothing. If the lag is only in those applications, we can reasonably assume the issue is with how they implement the mouse control, and not with your computer.

Comment: @music2myear I just tried it using Windows itself. Yes, I get the same effect, particularly when I flick the mouse across the mouse area.

Comment: Interesting, a post at https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/637718/mouse-lags-when-i-move-it-fast/ suggested running sfc /scannow, and a user  had some corrupt files. I seem to have the same...

Comment: Do you have the same corrupt files, or just some corrupt files?

Comment: @music2myear The other guy's corrupted files was never mentioned. My CBS.log mentions "cannot repair" 4 times. See edit for the lines.

Comment: That's a part of Windows Media Center. I doubt it has anything to do with your mouse issue.